# Hackerrank Challenge - Completed but don't understand optimal solution

Tags: c#, time-complexity

So I've completed the challenge that has the following link:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem

With the following code in C#:

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using System;

class Solution {

    // Complete the arrayManipulation function below.
    static long arrayManipulation(int n, int[][] queries) {
        long[] arr = new long[n];
        long count = 0;
        long largestValue = long.MinValue;

        for (int i = 0; i < queries.Length; ++i)
        {
            long startIndex = queries[i][0];
            long endIndex = queries[i][1];
            long numberToAdd = queries[i][2];

            for (long j = startIndex - 1; j <= endIndex - 1; ++j)
            {
                arr[j] += numberToAdd;
            }
        }

        return arr.Max();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH"), true);

        string[] nm = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

        int n = Convert.ToInt32(nm[0]);

        int m = Convert.ToInt32(nm[1]);

        int[][] queries = new int[m][];

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            queries[i] = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), queriesTemp => Convert.ToInt32(queriesTemp));
        }

        long result = arrayManipulation(n, queries);

        textWriter.WriteLine(result);

        textWriter.Flush();
        textWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

However, it fails on some test cases as it is not running at its optimal speed. I have read the explanation of how to make it better, but I'm not understanding it. It talks about adding `-k` to `i+1` and prefix sums and... to be honest I feel like a floundering fish with this one. I don't know if someone could potentially help explain or simply the explanation?

The optimal description says:

[image: description]

Comment: Do you understand what they mean when they say the straightforward solution is _**O(N x M)**_ but the optimal solution runs in _**O(M x log(M))**_?

Comment: I understand the prefix sum checking only 2 values of all the updates (worked out what the prefix sum algorithm is), but I don't get how they got to O(m log(m)) no....